# How to rotate rows into columns with PHP?

Tags: php

I have array with multiple rows like so:

```
username => 'john', type = 'smtp'
username => 'john', type = 'pop'
username => 'james', type = 'pop'
username => 'james', type = 'smtp'
```

I would like to display the data in a string like so:

```
john, smtp, pop
james, smtp, pop
```

That is, I need the multiple types to add to each username as a column.

Note: $accounts is an array of arrays.

```
$customers = array();

$pos = 0;
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
      if (array_key_exists('username', $account)) {
          $customers[$pos] .= "," . $account[type];
         }
         else
         {
          $customers[$pos] = $account[username] . "," . $account[type];   
         }

         $pos = $pos + 1;
         echo $pos;


}

print_r($customers);
```

You will have to excuse me as I am pretty new to PHP and my syntax might not perfect. I'm not sure if am using `array_key_exists` correctly.

Comment: So - what's your question?

Comment: I just need the values from the types to appear per username. So if a user has pop, and smtp, it should appear like: john, smtp, pop. How could I go about this?

Comment: u_mulder gave you an answer below, what's going on with that?

Answer (score 1):

You code can be rewritten as:

```
$accounts = [
    ['username' => 'john', 'type' => 1],
    ['username' => 'john', 'type' => 2],
    ['username' => 'james', 'type' => 3],
    ['username' => 'james', 'type' => 4],
];

$pos = 0;
$customers = array();
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    // collect each `type` under corresponding `username`
    $customers[$account['username']][] = $account['type'];
}

foreach ($customers as $customer => $types) {
    echo $customer . ', ' . implode(', ', $types) . PHP_EOL;
}
```