# How to print values of array on every line to text file in php?

Tags: php

I have an array `$customers`, and want to print each value of the array to a text file. Array looks like this:

```
[0] = Sam, John, Rick
[1] = Jacob, Richard, David
[2] = Jesse, Frank, Louise
```

This is what I had in mind, but it doesn't seem to like `implode`:

```
$pos = 0;
    foreach ($customers as $customer)
    {
      $result = implode(" ",$customers[$pos]);
      //echo implode(" ",$customers[$pos]);
      file_put_contents('active.txt', $result);
      $pos = $pos + 1;
    }
```

The result I would expect in the text file is:

```
Sam, John, Rick
Jacob, Richard, David
Jesse, Frank, Louise
```

Can anyone explain how to do this? The goal is to have the array to appear comma delimited in a text file to export to Excel.

Comment: Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php for creating a CSV file format

Comment: Why do you implode with space if it's comma you want. Not that it made any difference this time

Comment: Does your question have anything to do with [what you asked in this one you asked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61412873/1415724)

Comment: `file_put_contents()` overwrites file contents if the `FILE_APPEND` flag is not set. You end up with only the last line in your file. Also I suggest not to use `file_put_contents()` in a loop because it opens and closes the file every time. This is a lot of I/O operations which take a lot of (unnecessary) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of `$customers` is a single value, so rather than using a loop and imploding the strings, which also overwrite each other in the file.

You can just `implode()` the whole array with `PHP_EOL` for the line separator...

```
file_put_contents('active.txt', implode(PHP_EOL ,$customers));
```